# How to surround views with background colour? Android Studio Java

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

How could I turn the following UI:

[image]

into something like this:

[image]

My current code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#f2f2f2"
    tools:context=".WelcomePage">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/username"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="75dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="75dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="336dp"
            android:hint="Username"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textColorHint="@color/white"
            android:textSize="25dp"
            ></EditText>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/password"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="75dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="75dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="240dp"
            android:hint="Password"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textColorHint="@color/white"
            android:textSize="25dp"
></EditText>

... button xml code

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I've tried using a RelativeLayout but I can't figure it out. Basically, I just want to put those two edit texts in a black box. How could it be done?

Answer (score 0):

try to add View before both EditTexts and with background set to black and constraints that fills EditTexts, something like this:

```
<View
  android:background="@color/black"
  app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/username"
  app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/password"
  app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/username"
  app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/username"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your UI elements inside another layout (e.g LinearLayout) then set background color to that layout. This is how your layouts should be:

```
Parent Layout{
     LinearLayout{
        android:background="@color/black" // your desired color here 
        ...
        
       User Edittext{...}

       Password Edittext{...}
    }
```